# Styling dynamic elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I'm using `load()` to insert content into a `div` container and some of this content needs to be styled using **jQuery**.

Is there any way to load in the content with an external script without having to place `<script>` tags into the content itself?

Comment: Please show us your code. jsfiddle is very handy.

Comment: Can't use CSS to style it automatically? That would be ideal.

Comment: It looks like load() doesn't like working with remote files, is there another way I can go about this?

Comment: Any code samples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using css should work, you just declare css styles that will affect your loaded data and then they are considered when rendering without having to do anything else

If you need to do it with javascript you can use the complete callback of load function:

```
$('#yourDiv').load('content.html', function() {
  $("#yourDiv").find("#someDynamicallyLoadedElement").height(500); // do whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: For some of these, using CSS is a bit tricky e.g. I want the line-height of a figcaption to be set to the height of its containing figure.

Plus I also have some things like hide() set for parts of the content.

Comment: I totally just figured this out on my own, but thanks for confirming that I went about it the correct way!